# How to check if a try error happened (possibly using testthat) when it is not desired to return the error value?

Tags: r, try-catch, testthat

I want the function to produce an error in a `try` block if a condition is faced, and output one of the inputs without any change in the case of this error. Please note that I do not wish to create a list output or anything as I need to have consistent output. My question is how can I check that the error does occur for some values using `testthat`? For example, for the below function:

```
myfunc = function(x,y){
  try({
    if(x<0)
      stop("Negative X")
    y = y+x
  })

  return(y)
}
```

I want to test and ensure error does occur for x=-1:

I have tried:

```
library(testthat)
expect_error(myfunc(-1,2))
```

But I get:

```
Error in try({ : Negative X
Error: `myfunc(-1, 2)` did not throw an error.
```

Comment: Do you want your function to error (i.e., `stop`) AND return a value?

Comment: Yes, if `x` is not valid, I need to output an error in a log file (e.g. this method failed with these inputs) and output `y` in original class anyways.

Comment: I don't think `stop` is the right function. This is designed to "stop" a function. Maybe you just want to `writeLines` to a file or something?

Comment: in R you can't both throw an error and return a value for a single function call. Maybe you want to throw a `warning()` instead?

Comment: Please note that `stop()` is in a `try` block, so facing that will only lead to exiting the `try` block, outputting the error and evaluating the rest.

Comment: That's why `expect_error` did not recognise an error